# Creating datetime objects by delimiting provided time

Tags: python, datetime

I have been searching and found similar questions but am struggling particularly with this project.

I would like to create a datetime object from a date with the following format:

"07/19/22 7:35:15" or "07/06/22 7:54:46" or "06/28/22 10:39:24"

I understand how to delimit if I was doing the two separately but not sure how to delimit the entire string at once. Would it be best to separate them with a space and delimit them separately or is there a simpler route to go about this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried?  `datetime` can certainly handle strings that contain both date and time.

Comment: They are currently strings so I have tried delimiting them all the way out and then using those values to create datetime objects - I didn't know if there was a way to covert that entire string to a datetime object.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "delimiting them all the way out".  Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: The three strings you provided all have the format `%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S`? Have you looked at the [documentation for strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
date = '07/19/22 7:35:15'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime( date, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the whole thing in one go:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('07/19/22 7:35:15', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 19, 7, 35, 15)
```